# Notepad++ plugin - find and highlight text

Tags: c#, plugins, notepad++, scintilla

How do I set and remove color for the find text in a scintilla document by writing plugins for notepad++ in **c#**. I tried the following code:

`Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.GetCurrentScintilla(), SciMsg.SCI_STYLESETBACK, 0, 0xFFFF00);`

Help me to highlight a particular text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the [selection background color](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETSELBACK), then try:

```
Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.GetCurrentScintilla(),
                  SciMsg.SCI_SETSELBACK, 1, 0xFFFF00);
```

If you want to change the [selection foreground color](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETSELFORE), then try:

```
Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.GetCurrentScintilla(),
                  SciMsg.SCI_SETSELFORE, 1, 0xFF0000);
```

To reset the default color, pass `0` instead of `1`.