# highlighting selected line in active window with some colour c#(notepad++ plugin)

Tags: c#, notepad++, programmers-notepad

Hi am doing a notepad++ plugin using c#

what i need is ,show the active window between the given line number in some color. Lets say i have line number 2 and 8,then it has to highlight the notepad++ screen between line number 2 and 8 in green color.

> Reading from active window

```
        int length = (int)Win32.SendMessage(GetCurrentScintilla(), SciMsg.SCI_GETLENGTH, 0, 0);
        IntPtr ptrToText = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length + 10);
        Win32.SendMessage(GetCurrentScintilla(), SciMsg.SCI_GETTEXT, length+10, ptrToText);
        String InputFromActiveWindow = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrToText);
```

> code for focusing a selected line

```
       Win32.SendMessage(curScintilla, SciMsg.SCI_ENSUREVISIBLE, lineNumber, 0);
        Win32.SendMessage(curScintilla, SciMsg.SCI_GOTOLINE, lineNumber, 0);
        Win32.SendMessage(curScintilla, SciMsg.SCI_GRABFOCUS, 0, 0);
        Win32.SendMessage(curScintilla, SciMsg.SCI_GRABFOCUS, 0, 0);
```

> //Answer is

```
win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERDEFINE, 1, (int)SciMsg.SC_MARK_BACKGROUND);
            Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERSETBACK, 1, 0x99FF00);
            for (int linetobeHighlighted = StartLine; linetobeHighlighted <= EndLine; linetobeHighlighted++)
            {
                Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERADD, linetobeHighlighted, 1);
            }
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried?

Comment: i actually dont know what to try.what i tried so far is reading from active window. and also going to particular line when line number is given.code for reading from active window

Comment: @Richa Garg i have attached code to the question

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478948/notepad-plugin-find-and-highlight-text/21487725#21487725 to highlight the text

Answer (score 1):

For highlighting the selected text, Use

```
Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.GetCurrentScintilla(),
              SciMsg.SCI_SETSELBACK, 1, 0xFFFF00);
```

Refer [Notepad++ plugin - find and highlight text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478948/notepad-plugin-find-and-highlight-text/21487725) for more details

Comment: here i have manually go and select the text.instaed i should pass line number and highlighting should happen

Comment: win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERDEFINE, 1, (int)SciMsg.SC_MARK_BACKGROUND);
            Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERSETBACK, 1, 0x99FF00);
            for (int linetobeHighlighted = StartLine; linetobeHighlighted <= EndLine; linetobeHighlighted++)
            {
                Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._scintillaMainHandle, SciMsg.SCI_MARKERADD, linetobeHighlighted, 1);
            }